# Delete lines within polygon

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have two layers, one with lines, one with polygons. I want to delete lines that fully fall (contain) within the polygons. It seems really simple, but I can't figure this one out in either PostgreSQL/PostGIS or QGIS.

For the SQL I am trying:

```
delete from lines_test2
 where ( select a.geom, b.geom
 from lines_test2 a, straten b
 where st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom));
```

But it gives me the error: 'subquery must return only one column'. Clipping in QGIS isn't a viable option either, because it should only delete full lines not parts of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Select By location then delete selected rows in QGIS or join by within:

```
delete from ok_jl_riks_copy where id in (

select sub1.id from
(select *
from ok_jl_riks_copy jl) sub1

inner join

(select wkb_geometry from ok_ak_riks ak) sub2

on st_within(sub1.wkb_geometry, sub2.wkb_geometry)
)
```

All lines within the polygons are deleted:
[image]

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use an `EXISTS` expression:

```
DELETE
FROM   <lines> AS ln
WHERE  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   <poly> AS pl
  WHERE  ST_Within(ln.geom, pl.geom)
);
```

If the `ST_Within` check hits the first `TRUE` (selecting a truthy `1`), the sub-query terminates for the current row (no matter if there were more than one hit).

This is among the most efficient ways for when a table has to be traversed by row (as in an `UPDATE/DELETE`), or otherwise compared against a pre-selection (of e.g. `ids`).

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says you should only return a single column, so try:

```
delete from lines_test2
 where id = ( select a.id
 from lines_test2 a, straten b
 where st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom));
```

This assumes you have a unique ID column in your `lines_test2` data table.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another recipe, try maybe like it

```
SELECT ST_Difference(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom FROM line AS a CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom FROM polygon WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.geom, geom)) AS b;
```